# Install/Add chrome extension from Chrome Web Store using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I am developing test automation using Selenium with Java. I would like to install/add extension to chrome instance launched through Selenium. One way to install/add extension is using .crx file as follow.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File(ext_path));

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

But I would like to install/add extension from Chrome Web Store. Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install extension (packed/unpacked) to chrome with `options.addExtensions/addArguments` as mentioned here:- https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions

*alternative:* `Chromedriver` every time opens new chrome instance with temporary profile for the execution. To avoid this you can use existing profile with desired chrome extension installed *OR* you can send commands to already running instance of chrome which has desir d extension installed.

usually, inline/webstore installation of a Chrome extension can't be tested with `ChromeDriver`/`Selenium` alone, because of confirmation dialog.
you can use platform-specific hacks to click on the button (e.g. via AutoIt),