# Can I open an IE instance in chrome automatically

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a website that opens only in IE. Manually i am able to add the IE extension to chrome and run the website.
But is it possible with `selenium` to automatically open the website in chrome?

Comment: Why would you do that? No user is going to run IE inside of Chrome. Just use the IE driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried loading chrome extensions using selenium. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34222412/8708630) is a discussion regarding the same. This discussion uses java. So you'll have to correlate.

Comment: Apparently that website has some security features due to which it opens only in IE. so i have been trying to open it in chrome but was unable, when i added an IE extension to chrome it did work manually. I am even unable to run automation script on IE too as it has this IBM security thing, doesn't let the script run.

Comment: When you launch chrome using webdriver the extensions are not loaded. If you are able to access the website using a chrome extension then you will have to add the extension using webdriver itself. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994519/8708630) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34194674/8708630) will help you to understand what I mean. Then you can google how to do this in python.